# Изменение текста в Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-faq

Имеется ссылка на объект Label. Как поменять у этикетки текст? В интернете предлагают какой-то дурацкий вариант пихнуть в label изменяемый вариант string и менять уже его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашёл ответ. Нужно вызвать метод `config`

```
label.config(text = 'Новый текст')
```

Answer (score 1):

Либо можно присвоить новый текст вот так:

```
label_123['text'] = 'Новый текст'
```