# Вывод изменяющейся переменной

Tags: python, парсер, tkinter

Изучаю python для своего интереса и своими силами, поэтому знания так себе.
4 дня уже не могу понять как сделать. Парсим курс валюты, обновляем каждые 5 секунд и выводим. С консолью проблем нет.

```py
import requests
import time

def currency():

    url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd"

    response = requests.request("GET", url)

    mid = response.text

    try:
        mid = float(mid[8:16]) 
    except:
        try:
            mid = float(mid[8:15])
        except:
            try:
                mid = float(mid[8:14])
            except:
                try:
                    mid = float(mid[8:13])
                except:
                    try:
                        mid = float(mid[8:12])
                    except:
                        mid = float(mid[8:11])

    print(mid, end = '\r')
    time.sleep(5)
    return currency()

currency()
```

Но не понимаю как вывести **mid** через tkinter,в поле ввода или текстовое поле. Код своих попыток не вижу смысла выкладывать, там бред. Может это и невозможно, или скорее я в корне не прав был. Покажите примером пожалуйста. Пытаюсь учиться на практике и вот застрял, не дает покоя. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Изменение текста в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489753/Изменение-текста-в-label), [Sleep в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633670/sleep-в-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вывести текст в метку вам уже показали в другом ответе (`label['text']=value`). Но в вашем коде есть другие проблемы:

1. Бесконечный цикл реализованный через рекурсию. Глубина вложенности вызовов ограничена, у вас гарантировано в какой-то момент вылетит ошибка.
2. Бесконечный цикл блокирует графический интерфейс. Даже если вы добавите вывод текста в метку, вы ничего не увидите, т.к. из-за бесконечного цикла окно будет "зависшим". Для выполнения каких-то действий с определенной периодичностью в tkinter есть метод `after`.
3. В ответе вам приходит json, всю эту лестницу из try-except можно заменить декодированием json-строки в словарь и получением нужного поля.

С учетом вышесказанного:

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import json

def get_currency():

    url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd"

    response = requests.get(url)

    mid = json.loads(response.text)['mid']
    # или просто mid = response.json()['mid']

    label['text'] += mid + '\n'  # Текст будет добавляться в метку каждый раз с новой строки
    # или просто label['text'] = mid если нужно изменить текст, а не добавить

    # Запланировать выполнение этой функции через 2 секунды
    root.after(2000, get_currency)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

get_currency()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,буду изучать!

Answer (score 0):

> не понимаю как вывести mid через tkinter

Нечто вроде:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
ll = Label(width=50)

def disply():
    value = time.ctime()
    ll['text'] = value

b = Button(text='Отобразить', command=disply)
ll.pack()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое