# как мне отобразить в tkinter тексте надпись обозначил красным цветов текст полученный с помощью selenium на примере взял ссылку в контакте vk.com

Tags: python, tkinter, selenium

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.r = Tk()
        self.r.geometry()

        ataman = Frame(bg="black")
        ataman.pack(expand=0, fill=BOTH)
        ataman1 = Frame(bg="green")
        ataman1.pack(expand=0, fill=BOTH)
        self.btn1 = Button(ataman, text="Открыть браузер", bg="green", fg="#BBE6FF", activebackground="blue",
                           activeforeground="black", command=self.sava_browser, bd=3
                           ).pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N, padx=5, pady=15)
        self.btn2 = Button(ataman, text="Запуск", bg="green", fg="#BBE6FF", activebackground="blue",
                           activeforeground="black", bd=3, command=self.sava_driver,
                           ).pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N, padx=5, pady=15)

        self.ent1 = Entry(ataman, width=100, bg="green", bd=5, fg="#BBE6FF", selectbackground="black")
        self.ent1.pack(fill=X, anchor=N, padx=5, pady=15)
        self.lbl3 = Label(ataman1, text="надпись", bg="red", fg="#BBE6FF", width=10) # как мне тут получить надпись ту которую я получил из  browser = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'login_mobile_header')
        self.lbl3.pack(anchor=N, side=LEFT, padx=15, pady=15)

        lambda x: [self.lbl3.config(text="browser[0].text"),  self.action()]

        self.r.mainloop()

    def sava_browser(self):
        global browser
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        if self.ent1.get()[0:5] == "https":
            browser.get(self.ent1.get())
        elif self.ent1.get()[0:4] == "http":
            browser.get(self.ent1.get())
        else:
            browser.get(f"https://{self.ent1.get()}")

    def sava_driver(self):
        global browser
        time.sleep(5)
        browser = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'login_mobile_header') # использовал элемент из vk.com главная надпись ВКонтакте для мобильных устройств
        self.lbl3[browser[0].text]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window()
```

выдает вот такую ошибку при написание такое кода

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ATAMAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/ATAMAN/PycharmProjects/pythonProject9/ATAMAN.py", line 46, in sava_driver
    self.lbl3[browser[0].text]
  File "C:\Users\ATAMAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1652, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-ВКонтакте для мобильных устройств"
```

Comment: моя почта - tagger2010@yandex.ru

Comment: `self.lbl3.config(text=browser[0].text)`

Comment: Или `self.lbl3["text"] = browser[0].text`

Comment: Это прописать в функции?

Comment: Это прописать вместо `self.lbl3[browser[0].text]`

Comment: В целом, см. [Изменение текста в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489753)