# Python, TkInter. Не выводится ответ из функции в Label

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
new = 1
def factorialo():
    global new
    a = int(vvod.get())
    if a < 0:
        new = "Введите положительное число!"
    elif a == 0:
        exit()
    else:
        for i in range(1, a + 1):
            new = new * i
    return new

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Нахожедние факториала')
root.geometry("800x500")
print(root.geometry())

tkinter.Label(root, text="Нахождение факториала.").pack(pady=5)
tkinter.Label(root, text="Выход через ввод 0.").pack(pady=5)
vvod = tkinter.Entry(root, width=50, justify=tkinter.CENTER)
vvod.pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="Посчитать", command=factorialo).pack(pady=5)
tkinter.Label(root, text = new).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Недавно решил проблему с new is not defined и теперь в label вывода выводит единичику из начала кода, return будто не работает.

Comment: В самой функции результат в label и записывайте. Изменение значения глобальной переменной или возврат значения из функции никак на текст в label не влияет. Нужно прямо вручную менять текст. См. [Изменение текста в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489753/1365). Ну и глобальная переменная тут не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Надо присвоить Label к переменной и менять её текст с помощью метода `.config(text="текст")`
2. Тут глобальная переменная не нужна
3. Ввод может быть нулевым, факториал 0 равно 1

Вот пример кода:

```
import tkinter as tk

def factorialo():
    new = 1
    a = int(vvod.get())
    if a < 0:
        new = "Введите положительное число!"
    else:
        for i in range(1, a + 1):
            new = new * i       
    result_label.config(text=new)
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Нахожедние факториала')
root.geometry("800x500")
print(root.geometry())

tk.Label(root, text="Нахождение факториала.").pack(pady=5)
tk.Label(root, text="Выход через ввод 0.").pack(pady=5)

vvod = tk.Entry(root, width=50, justify=tk.CENTER)
vvod.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Посчитать", command=factorialo).pack(pady=5)

result_label = tk.Label(root, text="0")
result_label.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь и советы, учту :)

Comment: "Во время изучения tkinter лучше импортировать его так: from tkinter import *" - не нужно плохому людей учить

Comment: По твоему лучше импортировать tkinter и ttk, потом использовать как попало?  Не понимая что такое ttk смысл его использовать? Автор вопроса видно что только изучает tkinter. вряд ли он знает разницу между tkinter и ttk. А так да, ты прав, импортировать сразу весь tkinter - это плохая практика. Кто уже уже начал понимать как работает  tkinter, лучше пользоваться ttk

Comment: @bilal нужно показывать как импортировать по общепринятым хорошим практикам в Python, причем сразу, а не откладывать на потом. Если нужно - объяснить, почему нужно делать так, а не по-другому. Но не приучать сначала к плохому, чтобы потом человек не удивлялся, почему у него какой-нибудь класс Image перезатерся импортом из другого модуля.

Comment: Извини, я тебя неправильно понял. Думал ты имеешь ввиду почему использую виджеты tkinter, вместо ttk, как было в примере автора вопроса. Импорт tkinter подправил.